# What is the contents of the Request[] collection

Tags: asp.net

When I access the Request object as a collection, where does it get it's data from?

For example I know

```
Request["someKey"]
```

will return the value of either

```
Request.QueryString["someKey"]
```

or

```
Request.Form["someKey"]
```

depending on which is set.

Are any other collections searched (cookies, session)?

What happens is the key value pair exists in several of the collections?

I took a look in MSDN, but couldn't find much info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.request

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should read this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decompile this assembly and take a look at the source, it will look in `QueryString`, then `Form`, then `Cookies`, then `ServerVariables`, before finally returning `null` if none of them contain the item.

```
public string this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        string item = this.QueryString[key];
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = this.Form[key];
            if (item == null)
            {
                HttpCookie httpCookie = this.Cookies[key];
                if (httpCookie == null)
                {
                    item = this.ServerVariables[key];
                    if (item == null)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return item;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return httpCookie.Value;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return item;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah, how interesting. Thanks!

I wonder if there's any official docs on this?

Comment: @Ev. Set the `trace` mode of your page to `true` - you'll see it all. e.g. `<%@ Page Trace="true" %>`